# Python: What exceptions should I handle in this pieces of code?

Tags: python-3.x, exception

Not sure how or what exceptions should I take into account.

I have the following piece of code that handles default files to pass to the program if not specified.

```
if len(sys.argv)==1:
    fileName = "file1.txt"
else:
    fileName = sys.argv[1]
```

The other part of code is when opening the file:

```
with open(fileName) as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split(';')
               ....
               ....
               ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FileNotFoundError`.

Example below taking user input:

```
yourPath = input('Enter your path')
try:
    with open(yourPath) as fl:
        for i in fl:
            print(i)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Please enter correct path')
```

OR you can use `IOError`:

```
yourPath = input('Enter your path')
    try:
        with open(yourPath) as fl:
            for i in fl:
                print(i)
    except IOError:
        print('Please enter correct path')
```

OR if you are not sure about just use `except`:

```
yourPath = input('Enter your path')
        try:
            with open(yourPath) as fl:
                for i in fl:
                    print(i)
        except:
            print('Please enter correct path')
```